# how to combine/merge two json object in single json object

Tags: java, php, html

These is json Two object :
   [{ "dob":"0000-00-00",
        "token":"tokenenter",
        "facebook":"enterfb",
        "image_url":"urlinserted",
        "verification":"326098617"
    },
    {
        "success":"1"
    }]

i want to create something like this:

```
[{ "dob":"0000-00-00",
    "token":"tokenenter",
    "facebook":"enterfb",
    "image_url":"urlinserted",
    "verification":"326098617",   
    "success":"1"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you are working with php*

You can do something like this:

```
$arrayOfArrays = json_decode($json);
$mergedArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrayOfArrays);
```

If you know the exact items count you can do something like this:

```
$mergedArray = array_merge($arrayOfArrays[0], $arrayOfArrays[1], $arrayOfArrays[2]);
```

In `PHP >= 5.6` you can do:

```
$mergedArray = array_merge(...$arrayOfArrays);
```

Back to your example:

```
json_encode([$mergedArray]);
```

---

To keep the order of keys you may use this very basic function (must be adjusted to deal with multidimensional arrays):

```
function simple_array_merge(array $array1, array $array2) {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $mergedArray = [];

    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $mergedArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    require $mergedArray;
}
```

and now do:

```
$arrayOfArrays = json_decode($json);
$mergedArray = call_user_func_array('simple_array_merge', $arrayOfArrays);
```

Comment: [{ "dob":"0000-00-00",
    "token":"tokenenter",
    "facebook":"enterfb",
    "image_url":"urlinserted",
    "verification":"326098617"} 
, 
   { "success":"1"}
}]

now i want to move success object after verification

Comment: @MuhammadDaniyal You have to do this manually. You can either sort the array by key ascending/descending or do it manually. You may also write your own array_merge function that would push items to array and keep the order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

So, Here you have two objects in one array, the simple solution it's to merge the second object in the first object with a simple affectation. 
like the code below:

```
a=[{ 
 "dob":"0000-00-00",
 "token":"tokenenter", 
 "facebook":"enterfb", 
 "image_url":"urlinserted",
 "verification":"326098617" },
 {
     "success":"1"
 }
 ];
a[0].success=a[1].success
```

like that you will obtain an object that combine the two objects. And if you want to delete the second you can use :

```
delete a[1];
```

Or

```
a[1]=undefined
```

Good luck.

Comment: @Gothdo Yeah, of couse, I was a little busy, I added some explanations to my code. and I hope it's clear now. Thanks for remarks.

Comment: @gotdo thanks for suggestion . 

$o[] = $e + array('success' => "1" ); 

this work for me thanks for your time :D